# How to hide an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var r1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    var g1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    var b1=Math.floor(Math.random()*255)
    
    $(".color1").click(function (){
        $(this).css("background", "rgb(" + r1 + "," + g1 + "," + b1 + ")")
    })
    
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
            $target = $(event.target);   
               $target.addClass('clicked');
           });     
    })
    var numItems 
    var getfirstclass
    var getsecondclass
    $('div').click(function saveclassnames(){
        var getfirstclass=$(this).attr('class')
        console.log(getfirstclass)
        var getsecondclass=$(this).attr('class')
        console.log(getsecondclass)
        getfirstclass===null
        getsecondclass===null
    })
    
    $('div').click(function remove(){
        var numItems = $('.clicked').length
        if(numItems===2 && getfirstclass === getsecondclass){
            $('.clicked').css('opacity', '0')
        }
        else{
        $('.clicked').css('background', 'black')
    }
    })
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="color1"></div>
                <div class="color2"></div>
                <div class="color3"></div>
                <div class="color4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color5"></div> 
                <div class="color3"></div>
                <div class="color1"></div>
                <div class="color6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color7"></div>
                <div class="color6"></div>
                <div class="color8"></div>
                <div class="color5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="color7"></div>
                <div class="color8"></div>
                <div class="color4"></div>
                <div class="color2"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
```

I am trying to make a game called "Memory" (if 2 flipped cards are same, the cards will disappear, but if the cards are not the same, they will flip back). But there is a difference between the original one). I am using random colors instead of card pictures, but I cannot make `<div>` elements with the same `background-color` disappear, or flip back if they are not the same. Can someone explain to me why this code does not work?
Thanks.

Comment: visibility hidden

Comment: Your problem is bigger than the visibility:hidden issue. I would recommend restarting the code with new logic. You have 3 click event handlers on divs, which means you will never get the expected result, and instead of using a random color generator, use an array to pick random color css classes, because with a random color generator there is like 16 million variations (if not there is a lot).

Comment: yea, thanks, that helped a little)

Answer (score 0):

`opacity: 0;` hiding generates a lot of space although the element is not visible.
`background: black;` – the element needs to blend in with the background, otherwise it will not work (technically it won't work)
You can either do this:

```
$('yourItem').css({
  display: 'none'
});
```

Or, the "simplest way to hide an element":

```
$('yourItem').hide();
```

For more information see https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Thank u!! But, nah, that messed positions of another divs.

Comment: maybe you should use opacity:0; instead since you want the empty space thing

Comment: im actually using it, but it didnt work , i just tried visibility, hidden and it worked!! but only once(second time i clicked divs with same bg and it didint do the same as well.(

Comment: o i didn't think of that :/

Comment: Do u know how to fix that?

Comment: ```if(numItems===2 && getfirstclass === getsecondclass){
            $('.clicked').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        }```

Comment: idk how to fix :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`display: none`
If that messes with other stuff, use
`visiblity: hidden;`

Comment: Thank for answer! But ```visibilty: hidden;``` works only once(i mean when i click to second pair of cards with same background-color it doesnt hide elements anymore, if u know how to fix that, pleadse let me know.

Comment: Theres an error in the snippet so I can't really see what's happening

Comment: nah, there is nothing in console

Comment: Maybe use a z-index. Do you know what those are?

Comment: You could put the element at `z-index: -1` then turn it into `z-index:  1` when you need to.